# How to prevent colorbox on body click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am using colorbox which is working fine. I want to avoid it from getting closed by body click event. It should close when I click on close button. What would be the syntax for this.
I am using this code.

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth: 570, innerHeight: 300, scrolling: true});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: RTFM?
Settings: `overlayClose`; default: `true`; If false, disables closing Colorbox by clicking on the background overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
 $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth: 570, innerHeight: 300, scrolling: true, overlayClose: false});
```

Comment: This is the same code as the other answer, came later as the other answer and does not contain a description.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `overlayClose: false` attrubute to disable closing of colorbox on click of gray background.

Default value of `overlayClose` is `true`

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, 
                       innerWidth: 570, 
                       innerHeight: 300, 
                       scrolling: true, 
                       overlayClose: false});
```

More Information - [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)